# Get difference between two dates in business hours (Redshift)

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have two dates in this format and I'd like to find the difference between them in business hours.

2019-03-07 00:34:08

Let's assume a regular 9-5, Mon-Fri

Edit: Forgot to mention that this has to be a standard query. I'm doing this in a BI tool and they don't support UDFs yet. So this isn't technically amazon redshift but I couldn't find the tag.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually quite a complex problem because it involves:

- Hours within a day
- Skipping non-business hours outside of 9-5
- Skipping weekends

The best way to approach this requirement would be to [Create a Scalar Python UDF - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-udf.html) that takes an input of two dates, then outputs the difference.

There are lots of Python libraries and sample code on the Internet to calculate the time, eg: [How to find the number of hours between two dates excluding weekends and certain holidays in Python? BusinessHours package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42409274/174777)