# How would one go around creating a due by attribute in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am currently trying to calculate due by dates in a table by adding the sla time to the time the request was created. From what I am able to understand, the way to go around this is to create a table with the work days and hours and query that table to find the due date. However, redshift does not allow one to declare variables. I was wondering how I would go around creating a work hour table in redshift and if that is not possible, how I would calculate the due date by other means. Thanks!

Comment: Please Edit your question to clarify your requirements. You mention 'work days' and 'work hours', so presumably you want them involved in a calculation somehow? What is that calculation -- is it a given number of 'work hours' taking into account day of week? This could be accomplished via a Scalar User Defined Function. Do you need to exclude Holidays?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you would like to provide a timestamp and then calculate the timestamp that is '*n work hours later'*, most probably taking into account certain rules such as:

- Weekdays: 9am-5pm
- Weekends: No Hours
- Holidays: Occasional weekdays with No Hours

This could be done by [Creating a scalar Python UDF - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-creating-a-scalar-udf.html) that would be passed a 'start' timestamp and a number of hours, and would return the 'end' timestamp.

Please note that Scalar UDFs cannot access tables or 'call outside' of Redshift, so it would need to be self-contained.

There is code on the web that shows [How to find the number of hours between two dates excluding weekends and certain holidays in Python? BusinessHours package - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42409274/how-to-find-the-number-of-hours-between-two-dates-excluding-weekends-and-certain). You would need to modify such code to *specify* the duration rather than *finding* the duration.

The alternate method of "creating a work hour table" would work well when trying to find the number of work hours *between two timestamps* but would be a bit harder when trying to *add workhours* to a timestamp.